# ImageMagick – Split Transparency Image Along Internal Non-transparent Object Borders

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, crop

I have a transparent image containing three non-transparent objects, each separated by transparency. Is there a simple command—not one with zillions of options, arguments and random geek walks inside the pic—to explode this picture into its three parts, each in a picture file.

Please, visit [this link](https://www.world-lolo.com/images/uploads/image.num1536154851.of.world-lolo.com.png) to view the kind of pic.

I thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I see a tall vertical bar, a large rectangle, a small rectangle and 4 letters. Which 3 objects do you mean? What OS do you use?

Comment: Are the objects always the same size and in the same place?

Comment: In fact, I'm only interested in the large black area (with its green spots); always same size and location.

Comment: The very first line of my answer is what you need then.

Comment: Thank you for your time and precious help. I can now automate on hundreds of pics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the 3 components you want are always in the same place, you can just extract according to coordinates:

```
convert image.png -crop 164x146+27+0 +repage result-0.png
convert image.png -crop 12x146+0+0   +repage result-1.png
convert image.png -crop 30x7+138+151 +repage result-2.png
```

[image]

[image]

The last one is empty!

---

If they are not always in the same place, I would look at the image's alpha/transaprency layer:

```
convert image.png -alpha extract alpha.png
```

[image]

As it shows the bits you want on white, I would look for white blobs, using *"Connected Component Analysis"*

```
convert image.png -alpha extract                  \
  -define connected-components:verbose=true       \
  -define connected-components:area-threshold=200 \
  -connected-components 4 -normalize result.png
```

**Output**

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
2: 164x146+27+0 108.5,72.5 23944 srgb(255,255,255)
3: 32x161+174+0 196.5,87.0 2670 srgb(2,2,2)
5: 174x15+0+146 79.8,152.8 2370 srgb(1,1,1)
1: 15x146+12+0 19.0,72.5 2190 srgb(2,2,2)
0: 12x146+0+0 5.5,72.5 1752 srgb(255,255,255)
39: 30x7+138+151 152.5,154.0 210 srgb(255,255,255)
```

That shows us all the blobs in your image. Looking back at the alpha layer, you only want the white ones and you want the second field on the line because that tells you where to crop that blob.

That leads us to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Edit this according to your input image name
image="image.png"

i=0
convert "$image" -alpha extract                    \
   -define connected-components:verbose=true       \
   -define connected-components:area-threshold=200 \
   -connected-components 4 -normalize result.png | 
      awk '/255,255,255/{print $2}'              | 
         while read c ; do
            convert "$image" -crop "$c" +repage result-$i.png
            ((i=i+1))
         done
```

which hopefully does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

If on a Unix-like system, you could try my multicrop2 bash script that uses ImageMagick. It is a script that is very similar to Mark Setchell's code example with a few more bells and whistles added.

Input:

[image]

```
multicrop2 -b none -f 1 -u 3 image.png results.png
```

It will extract each object like Mark's usage of -connected-components, which my script also uses. The -b none tells the script that the background color is transparent. The -f 1 means separate the background from the objects using a fuzz value of 1%. The -u 3 means no unrotation of the resulting images.

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you do not care about the letters, you can do

```
multicrop2 -b none -f 1 -u 3 -d 100 test.png results2.png
```

The -d 100 discards any region that contains less than 100 contiguous pixels. So you will get only the first 3 images shown above.

See my scripts at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Comment: I visited the website. Very unfortunately, I can't test your script on my side for confirmation. I'm on OS X and can't find any reliable app to extract DMS archives. I no longer trust *The Unarchiver* app because of its parent company.

Comment: Just discovered it's a plain text file; `mv multicrop2.{dms,sh}` – Script tested successfully on my side. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, bash shell scripts are simple text files.

Comment: damn.... your scripts are amazing, thank you so much for it, even more for this one, was looking for something like that for a long time and on first try it did the job perfectly when extracted individually many art pieces of a image sheet with hundreds of sprites on a 50MP png file, I really appreciate this!. ^^