# How to crop rectangles surrounded by black without know the coordinates?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, imagemagick, crop

I have the image below with almost all background in black.
[image]
Is there a way to crop rectangles surrounded by black without know the coordinates, were:

1. height > 400px
2. height about 144px
3. height about 40px

I'm not interested in the blue rectangle (were height is about 45px) that is above each big rectangle.
[image]
I'd like to store the cropped rectangles in memory in order to make further processing with them. So for this
input image would be 4 images stored in memory like below. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Image 1:**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

**Image 3:**

[image]

**Image 4:**

[image]

**UPDATE2**

I understand why the output is different for me. I tried your script with my actual input image (see below), that has gray background, and your script takes as input the black background image I show as input in this question. I've shown the black background image because I made some attempts previously to get my goal with imagemagick in bash.

[image]

Comment: In a bit of a rush to do it all, but try something like this to simplify your image to pure-ish black and white   `magick YOURIMAGE -fill white -fuzz 10 +opaque black -morphology dilate disk:2 result.png`

Then try connected components like this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/28429090/2836621

Comment: See also here for piping connected components output into `awk` to find objects of given shape and colour https://stackoverflow.com/a/52188937/2836621

Comment: Remember you can change colours, simplify, threshold and do morphology to find locations of shapes, then go back to original full colour image with the coordinates you find in order to get the full-colour data.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do it all in one go in **ImageMagick** and extract the blocks and have them *"in memory"* in one go. I think you'll need to simplify the image first, find the components, parse them out with `awk` or `bash` or similar and then start a new **ImageMagick** command that cuts out the chunks and processes them. You could do it all in one go with **OpenCV** if you know Python.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm interested to make it in Python. Which would be the equivalent commands to simplify the image and then to crop it? If you can share me some good link or need to open a new question for opencv?

Comment: Not sure what to suggest. Maybe look at some questions tagged OpenCV - put "[opencv]" in Search box above. Then add a code attempt into your question and change its tags. You want to 1) open it 2) cvtColor(BGR2GRAY) to get greyscale 3) change all non-black pixels to white - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019059/2836621 4) do some morphology maybe to clean up 5) `findContours()`

Comment: Thank you, Thank you. I'll check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can do the following in Imagemagick 7 to get each non-black-containing regions using connected components filtering.

Threshold. Then get any region larger than 20000 pixels in area. Then keep only the white ones, i.e. gray(255). Then print only the  bounding boxes of the regions. Then loop over each region and filter on height an also on standard deviation (to discard near constant regions). Then crop those regions that pass.

```
cropboxArr=(`magick charts.png -alpha off \
-threshold 1% -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=20000 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:exclude-header=true \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 8 cleaned.png | grep "gray(255)" | awk '{print $2}'`)
num=${#cropboxArr[*]}
echo $num
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
cropbox=${cropboxArr[$i]}
echo "$i; $cropbox;"
ww=`echo $cropbox | tr "x" "+" | cut -d+ -f1`
hh=`echo $cropbox | tr "x" "+" | cut -d+ -f2`
xo=`echo $cropbox | tr "x" "+" | cut -d+ -f3`
yo=`echo $cropbox | tr "x" "+" | cut -d+ -f4`
if [ $hh -gt 40 ]; then
magick charts.png -alpha off -crop $cropbox +repage tmp.png
std=`magick tmp.png -format "%[fx:standard_deviation]" info:`
std_test=`magick xc: -format "%[fx:($std>0.1)?1:0]" info:`
echo "$std; $std_test"
echo ""
if [ $std_test = 1 ]; then
mv tmp.png charts_$i.png
fi
fi
done
```

Resulting Crops:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**ADDITION**

Here is an alternate that get the full rows of regions.

```
ht_thresh=40
cropboxArr=(`im7 magick charts.png -set option:area "%[fx:w*$ht_thresh]" -alpha off \
-threshold 1% \
-scale 1x! \
-threshold 25% -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:area-threshold="%[area]" \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:exclude-header=true \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 8 cleaned.png | grep "gray(255)" | awk '{print $2}'`)
num=${#cropboxArr[*]}
echo $num
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
cropbox=${cropboxArr[$i]}
echo "$i; $cropbox;"
ww=`echo $cropbox | tr "x" "+" | cut -d+ -f1`
hh=`echo $cropbox | tr "x" "+" | cut -d+ -f2`
xo=`echo $cropbox | tr "x" "+" | cut -d+ -f3`
yo=`echo $cropbox | tr "x" "+" | cut -d+ -f4`
if [ $hh -gt $ht_thresh ]; then
im7 magick charts.png -alpha off -crop "%wx$hh+$xo+$yo" +repage -trim +repage tmp.png
std=`im7 magick tmp.png -format "%[fx:standard_deviation]" info:`
std_test=`im7 magick xc: -format "%[fx:($std>0.13)?1:0]" info:`
echo "$std; $std_test"
echo ""
if [ $std_test = 1 ]; then
mv tmp.png charts_$i.png
fi
fi
done
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your name for the input and try with full path if you do not have the image in your working directory.

Comment: If you are on Cygwin, you need to run the command not in CMD window but in a Cygwin bash terminal window.  Sorry, it is too late tonight for me to look at your gray background image and change the tuning arguments. I will look into it tomorrow.  The gray background image should in principle only need to change the first threshold. But things are often not so simple. I will test tomorrow.

Comment: I looked at your gray border image and this cannot be processed easily.  Your gray border has values that are both lower and higher than the white regions in your image. So thresholding by several means that I have tried does not work as it removes some of your regions that you want to save or merges multiple regions in ways you do not want. You would have to do many very selective thresholds or flood fills picking specific regions to start the fill.

Comment: I was able to get the image with black background that you use in your solution as input image doing this `magic wand` like process, but I don´t know how to add it at the beggining of your script `magick gray_background.png -alpha off \
   -fuzz 12% -fill black -draw "color 980,350 floodfill" \
   -fuzz 0%  -fill black -opaque '#B4CEF8' \
   -fuzz 0%  -fill black -opaque '#EEEEEE' black_background.png`

Comment: Change my name to your name in the script and put the full path to your name if the image is not in your working directory.

Comment: You have not shown me your script.  But I tried flood fill and it does not work due to the fact that your gray has regions brighter than your white parts of the charts and also other regions where it is smaller. So there is not one range of gray thresholds that can be used (via -fuzz) for the flood fill.  You would have to do several floodfills to get all gray turned to black. Show me your code and I will see how to add it to my script even though it won't work.  Or do your own flood fill and save your image to disk. Then change the input to my script.

Comment: This is the script that uses as input the gray border image and converts it in black border image `magick gray_background.png -alpha off \    -fuzz 12% -fill black -draw "color 980,350 floodfill" \    -fuzz 0%  -fill black -opaque '#B4CEF8' \    -fuzz 0%  -fill black -opaque '#EEEEEE' black_background.png`

Comment: Replace my black border image name with `gray_background.png -alpha off -fuzz 12% -fill black -draw "color 980,350 floodfill"  -fuzz 0%  -fill black -opaque '#B4CEF8'  -fuzz 0%  -fill black -opaque '#EEEEEE'` in my script.

Comment: Thanks so much. It works doing that. Even I don't understand how it works your script it does very nice. I'll try to understand it in order to make the further processing for the cropped images.

Answer (score 1):

Per the discussion, you seem happy to go with an OpenCV solution, so I made you one. I didn't pay too much attention to extracting the exact items you were looking for with all the criteria, I just extracted all the contours taller than 35px. You can dink around with the exact heights/widths/colours that interest you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Load image and make greyscale version
im = cv.imread('uvXcA.png')
grey = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-grey.png', grey)

# Threshold image to get white regions of interest on black background
_, thr = cv.threshold(grey,0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-thr.png', thr)

# Morphology to get rid of small artefacts
SE = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
cleaned = cv.morphologyEx(thr, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, SE)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-cleaned.png', cleaned)

# Find "interesting" objects
contours, _ = cv.findContours(cleaned, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for i,c in enumerate(contours):
   # Get bounding rect of this contour
   x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(c)
   # Print if taller than 35 px
   if h>35:
      print(f'Contour: {i}, {w}x{h} @ {x},{y}')
      # Extract from original colour image, not the one we morphed
      extracted = im[y:y+h, x:x+w]
      cv.imwrite(f'DEBUG-contour{i}.png', extracted)
```

---

This is the output from the program:

```
Contour: 4, 894x62 @ 1001,1521
Contour: 5, 894x62 @ 70,1521
Contour: 6, 892x630 @ 1002,876
Contour: 9, 892x630 @ 71,876
Contour: 10, 892x531 @ 1002,330
Contour: 94, 892x531 @ 71,330
Contour: 98, 428x144 @ 1467,155
Contour: 99, 428x144 @ 1001,155
Contour: 100, 429x144 @ 535,155
Contour: 101, 428x144 @ 70,155
Contour: 106, 564x42 @ 1331,110
Contour: 107, 44x48 @ 0,101
Contour: 108, 1920x81 @ 0,0
```

---

These are the debug images in the order that the processing generates them, and also some of the extracted images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Mark. You gave a real good example before I was able to fix the opencv installation. I had issues installing it. Please check my update. I'm getting different output for `DEBUG-thr.png` and not sure why.

Comment: Try increasing the 0 in this line `_, thr = cv.threshold(grey,0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)` to 5 or 10 or more in case your black background isn't really black but just dark. That code makes everything less than or equal to zero black and everything else becomes white (255)

Comment: Thanks. Please see my second update. I found why the differences, was not the tool but the actual input image.